# Unity3D : LineRenderer cut by camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, perspectivecamera

I use a `LineRenderer` to represent a "laser beam" in my game.

However, when the beam goes backwards (ie. the end point is behind the player), the camera cuts the line.

A screenshot to explain the situation :

[image: LineRenderer cut by camera]

In blue : my laser beam. In dashed red : the behavior I want.

As I see it, the problem is that the camera is a rectangle, and not a zero dimension point (as is the human eye, more or less).

Is there a way to cheat this and get the line to go to the edge of the screen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the near clip plane smaller. But this will increase the chances of z-buffer conflict (you will see some weird shapes on textures).

Near clip plane pretty much ignores anything closer to the camera than that value and same for far clip plane. So by making it 0.01 (smallest value), you get to see more. But again, z-buffer is getting a big hit and you will start seeing some black semi-transparent shape here and there. You can limit that effect by reducing the far clip plane. So it is just a matter of finding the right values.

Comment: Don't have any bug for now, and works (almost) like a charm (still cut when the beam is right at the center of the camera, but hey !)

Comment: Was a typo, the weird thing is not a bug, I mean big hit, not bug hit, it is a technology limitations. If you want to see it, make you far clip plane big enough and your near small enough. Then as you move around, at some angle, you will see the shapes on large textures.